Excel File is not getting downloaded using waitforEvent('download')
await this.page.waitForEvent('download').then(blobFile => {
    blobFile.saveAs(testFolder + '/' + testCaseFileName + blobFile.suggestedFilename())
    this.page.waitForTimeout(10000);
    fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(async file => {
        if (file.includes("Summary") && file.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            filepath = await (testFolder + '/' + file);
            await console.log("Summary Report generated successfully");
        }
    });
})


This is my code, it shows the file is downloaded when I check in headed mode. However, the file is not downloaded in the designated path.
and fails at waitforEvent('download')
I tried page.on('download) which also shows that the file is downloaded, but it is not. It gives the below error while trying to read file as file is not present
TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

I am using playwright version 1.44.1.

Without a website or complete runnable code, this isn't reproducible. Which line is throwing?

You could just console.log whatever you are passing as the path parameter to the function that throws. That way you can verify that it's indeed a string or undefined as the error mentions.

Change this line:
filepath = await (testFolder + '/' + file);

Into this:
filepath = testFolder + '/' + file;

You do Not need the await here, you are just adding strings.
